# Problems resolving ts.d from systemjs

Tags: typescript, commonjs, jspm, systemjs

I'm using jspm and have installed a package. I have checked that the package.json defines 'main' and 'typings' since i have installed typescript 1.6 i expected to be able to import the typings at design time and the javascript at runtime per https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Typings-for-npm-packages

what is strange is this does not work. I get cannot find the module 'theModule'

```
import {x,y,z} from 'theModule';
```

but if i do a relative path it works fine

```
import {x,y,z} from '../jspm_packages/github/blah/blah/dist/theModule';
```

I have tried everything i can think of but i just cant seem to get this to work. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New module resolution in tsc 1.6 assumes that the definition is in `node_modules` folder - that is not your case.

Therefore you need to make a hint where tsc should look for definition of the module.

The easiest way how to reference the d.ts which defines global module and then use it.

```
/// <reference path="../jspm_packages/github/blah/blah/dist/theModule.d.ts" />

import {x,y,z} from 'theModule';
```

As @DeanB_Develop mentioned in real projects use [tsconfig](https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/tsconfig.md) and [tsd](http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/).

Comment: Avoid using `///<reference path`.  Instead, use tsconfig.json for compileroptions and files. You can then add `../jspm_packages/github/blah/blah/dist/theModule.d.ts` to the files element and it will work on all .ts files.  Better yet, use TSD to download and manage d.ts files.  Then add the tsd.d.ts to the files element.


@basarat has great information about tsconfig.  Check it out [https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/tsconfig.md](https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/tsconfig.md)